# React-native project error "could not connect to development server"

Tags: android, react-native

When I run "react-native run-android", it gives me the error:

> could not connect to development server...

So I had to start my project as follows:

- Going to the **android** folder running `./gradlew clean`
- In root folder `react-native run-android`.
- Only after that the project run's.

I have to repeat this cycle *every time* I run my project.
Is there any permanent solution to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Quicker solution: run `npm start` when you get error `could not connect to development server...` happens.

A permanent solution may require you to reinstall or update most of your dev tools.